# CreateProcess failed with error 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

В Webstorm 2016.3.2 запускаю javascript-код на исполнение и появляется такая ошибка. Что не так?

CreateProcess failed with error 2: �� ������� ����� ��������� ����.

Comment: ну для начала с кодировкой разберитесь... текста ошибки то не видно.. ну или в документации искать код такой ошибки

Comment: @Volodymyr Это ошибка вылезает в окне Run, где в вебшторме посмотреть кодировку этого окна? Кодировка самого файла UTF-8

Comment: Ошибка 2 - это "файл не найден". Что неудивительно, если кодировка кривая.

Comment: Похоже на то, что текст ошибки в windows-1251 пытается обработаться как UTF-8. Кодировка файла не верная возможно

Comment: @Akina спасибо. Понял в чем дело было. Я клонировал свой же репозиторий на другой компьютер. Далее я пытался перейти на ранее созданные ветки, которые пока в ПР, пока не смержены они.